# When deploy a working code to production server it gives "Only a type can be imported. "

Tags: java, jsp, osgi, jsp-tags

This is a weird problem. I have some "working" code,  the code has been tested on dev without a problem. But when I deploy it to the production environment, it gives a `"Only a type can be imported"` error.

So I went through that error page and found this is causing the problem.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.myfirm.utils.CommonUtil"%>
```

If I change it to `import="com.myfirm.utils.*"`, it starts getting working. After that even though I roll back to `import="com.myfirm.utils.CommonUtil"` and it's still working...

Anyone knows why this could happen? This is scary because I don't know if this is a server issue or code issue?

Comment: Unless you are using a non-standard naming convention, it looks like `my.test` is a package, which it doesn't make sense to import anyway - it's not a type, like the error message says.

Comment: Andy, I have updated my edit. This is the actual import naming.